# Using Secured Annotation for Controller in combination with CGLib and Mybatis Spring

Tags: spring, security, proxy, mybatis, cglib

I hope someone can help me for this issue:

I want to use the following security configuration:

`<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />`

The reason for using CGLib as proxy instead of the JDK dynamic proxy is because of the usage of extending interfaces like this:

```
public abstract interface AbstractPromotionController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void edit(final Model model, @RequestParam(value = "foo", required = false) final String foo, final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException;
}

@RequestMapping("/foo/bar/blubb")
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" })
public interface AmAktionController extends AbstractPromotionController {
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because the JDK dynamic proxy looses the RequestMapping information if inheritance is used, isn't it?!

So I tried using the `proxy-target-class="true"`  property above.
But this seems doesn't to work in combination with the mybatis spring MapperFactoryBean, which I want to use to dynamically generate the DAO implementations:

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
   <property name="mapperInterface" 
       value="com.foo.bar.dao.api.admin.servicestatistic.StatisticLogDAO" />
   <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

These configurations produces the following exception:

`2013-01-24 10:30:12,216 [main] [ERROR] [] ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pidbStatisticLogServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.foo.bar.dao.api.admin.servicestatistic.StatisticLogDAO com.foo.bar.service.impl.admin.servicestatistic.PidbStatisticLogServiceImpl.statisticLogDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean#4': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy25]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.foo.bar.dao.api.admin.servicestatistic.StatisticLogDAO com.foo.bar.service.impl.admin.servicestatistic.PidbStatisticLogServiceImpl.statisticLogDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean#4': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy25]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean#4': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy25]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy25]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:217)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    [...]`

Is there any solution for this issue? Can I change the behaviour of the mybatis spring org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean how to create the proxy which would work in combination with the `proxy-target-class="true"` property of the spring security configuration?

Please help me.
I'm using spring 3.2.0, spring security 3.1.3 and mybatis spring 1.1.1

Thanks,
Oilid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations of interfaces are not inherited from implementing classes since it is unclear what shoulg happen if two interfaces with the same annotation and different values were implemented by the same class. If you generate a dynamic proxy manually, you have to move the interface annotation to the proxy class.